# Rails / Angular: Different returned JSON dev/production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails backend, AngularJS frontend Single Page Application. It makes various ajax calls, which return JSON objects for the front end to use.

I'm using a postgres database for both development and production, served by heroku.

For a particular JSON call, I'm getting very different objects returned.

On development, it looks like this:

[image]

On production, it comes back looking like this:

[image]

What!? Is this minification at play?

Thanks greatly for any help.

**Ok, here are the server requests**

```
2014-12-05T12:37:14.608517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/itemprices/fromcleaner/80.json" host=www.60secondlaundry.com request_id=334d5cea-44bf-45d5-86a9-66e7fa8ea23e fwd="92.237.49.190" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=54ms status=304 bytes=467

2014-12-05T12:37:14.534106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/items.json" host=www.60secondlaundry.com request_id=4ba6050a-ea4e-4ba7-96a7-87cb111a811e fwd="92.237.49.190" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=304 bytes=467

2014-12-05T12:37:14.570669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/cleaners/80.json" host=www.60secondlaundry.com request_id=b3016b72-3653-4a5e-9410-5bc2a797c300 fwd="92.237.49.190" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=467

2014-12-05T12:37:14.772106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/reviews/fromcleaner/80.json" host=www.60secondlaundry.com request_id=25fe479e-cf86-4fd9-bc56-19536b9e83c2 fwd="92.237.49.190" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=212ms status=304 bytes=467
```

**Here's the response**

The response is essentially what you see in the screenshots above.

This is the line of code that prints out the two screenshots above:

```
  Reviews.get(cleanerid).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("getting reviews")
    $scope.reviews = data.reviews
    console.log(data.reviews)
  });
```

Here's the "Reviews" factory object in the code above.

```
app.factory("Reviews", ['$http', function($http) {
    var reviews = {};
    reviews.get = function(id) {
      return $http.get("/api/reviews/fromcleaner/" + id + ".json")
    }
    return reviews;
  }]);
```

Comment: Could you share the raw output from the server requests?

Comment: Could someone kindly explain why this has been downvoted? Is my question not clear enough / not enough information has been provided?

Comment: @gernberg: Sure. Will just update the answer above

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I meant the raw response from the requests.
Could it simply be because the data is different on development and production? Did you try to copy the prod db to dev?

Comment: Would the serverside code be helpful?